# 2021 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/5#questionnaire).**

---

Ask Different is scheduled for an election [next week, 2021-08-16](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/5). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2021-08-16 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/5). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: The first bullet point says (emphasis mine): "Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2021-08-16 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), **this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates.** Please only post one question per answer."

Comment: JNat, thanks for getting the elections going. IMHO the questions we used in the previous elections still look good, shall we just copy them from https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?

Comment: That's perfectly fine, and very common — often users who do it just point to the previous post where they got it from, as a way of attributing authorship, @nohillside

Comment: Yes, @uhoh, please post your question proposals as answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

How would you handle situations involving less than warm welcomes given to new users?

For example, a new user posts a well written first question consisting of a clearly defined problem statement, admission of a high level of domain ignorance, and a request for the proper solution methodology, but no actual attempts to tackle the problem.

Said question receives many downvotes and impolite comments. The asker gets upset about the situation and complains to you directly on chat and/or meta.

What would you do?

(taken from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220323/193295)

Answer (score 2):

How would you handle a single user that is upset at a moderator action you have taken?

For example, if someone posted on meta "This mod deleted my [question|answer|comment] and he is abusing his power," how would you react?

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220386/193295

Answer (score 1):

As a user of this site, what would you say is the number one issue we face moving forward? And, do you have any thoughts on how we tackle that issue?

From https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3082/9058

Answer (score 1):

How would you deal with complaints about a user successfully suggesting a large number of low-quality edits?

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220321/193295

Answer (score 0):

A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

From https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3074/9058

Comment: This is already one of the "additional" questions.